# Why was a clone army needed to eradicate the Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars

If we remove *Star Wars: The Clone Wars - The Lost Missions (Unfinished Season 6)* from our view, what was original thing Lucas wanted to tell about this? Why did Palpatine order a Clone Army for his grand plan? Couldn't any other army do? Definitely, any army would follow *Order 66*. Also, there was a possibility that Jedi Council and Senate wouldn't accept that Clone Army. After coming into power, couldn't he order for a grand army creation or simply officially order a clone army?

Comment: "any army would follow Order 66." After fighting prolonged wars along side the Jedi, I'd imagine most soldiers would *not* be quite so willing to turn around and murder their friends. The Clones were genetically programmed to do so if instructed.

Comment: @phantom42: Even then, some exceedingly small number of clones ***did*** resist the order.

Comment: @phantom42 You are talking about genetically programmed thing from *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*..

Comment: Even if you think the programming isn't canon, Lama Su specifically says they're genetically bred and altered to be more obedient in *AotC*. "We modified their genetic structure to make them less independent than the original host. As a result they are totally obedient, taking any order without question."

Comment: the clone army is something you can prepare ahead of time, as they take years to produce, so for someone like palpatine who has been planning this for years it was the best thing to do. otherwise you have to go find people, train them, and have them all ready to fight in 20ish years.

Comment: "After coming into power, couldn't he... simply officially order a clone army?" Yes. That's pretty much what he did. But isn't it a lot more convenient to have the army already created when you want it, rather than waiting years for their growth and training?

Comment: @phantom42 but it really doesn't matter whether S S thinks it's canon or not, because it just is.

Comment: Out of universe, when Lucas was writing Star Wars the phrase "the Clone Wars" sounded cool. #RuleOfCool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at [the Attack of the Clones script for answers](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html)

> *LAMA SU*:
>   We modified their genetic
>   structure to make them less
>   independent than the original
>   host. As a result they are
>   totally obedient, taking any order
>   without question.

(snip)

> *OBI-WAN*:
>   You mentioned growth
>   acceleration...
>
> *LAMA SU*:
>   Oh yes, it's essential.
>   Otherwise, a mature clone would
>   take a lifetime to grow. Now, we
>   can do it in half the time. Those
>   items you saw on the parade ground
>   were started ten years ago, when
>   Sido-dyas first placed the order,
>   and they're already mature...

(snip)

> *LAMA SU*
>   They're immensely superior to
>   droids, capable of independent
>   thought and action.

**Why did Palpatine order a Clone Army for his grand plan?**

Palpatine wanted an army that was intelligent, effective, and obedient. The clone army fits all of these criteria - and could be created in secret and revealed exactly when he was ready to use them.

**Couldn't any other army do? Definitely, any army would follow Order 66.**

A droid army is the only other type of army that would be 100% obedient. The clone troopers spend years fighting alongside the Jedi. The average soldier is not going to turn and kill their friends without hesitation just because their commanding officers/commander in chief tells them to. The clones were genetically modified to obey any order, and no order could supercede the Chancellor's.

**Also, there was a possibility that Jedi Council and Senate wouldn't accept that Clone Army.**

This is a possibility - but Palpatine engineered events so that the Jedi would discover the Separatist Droid Army and the Clone Army at the same time. With no other standing army to battle the Separatists, a clone army genetically bred to be loyal to the Republic is going to be awfully hard for them to turn down.

**After coming into power, couldn't he order for a grand army creation or simply officially order a clone army?**

He could order the creation of a non-clone army, but would have to deal with issues of loyalty and quality. He could order a new clone army, but as Lama Su explains, it takes time for them to be grown. The clone army was commissioned 10 years ago, and is only now ready. That's far too long if they are to fight the Separatists.