# How does Obi-Wan reconcile the fact that the Separatists apparently commissioned the clone army for the Republic?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In Episode 2, Obi-Wan Kenobi talked to Jango Fett on Kamino. Jango was clearly working under whoever hired/commissioned the clone army. Not minding that Jango told him that he was hired by Darth Tyrannus, he tracked Jango straight to the Separatist base planet where he is clearly seen working for Count Dooku and the Separatists.

Maybe Obi-Wan could have figured that as a bounty hunter, Jango had no loyalty, and had no trouble working for both the mysterious people who ordered the clone army and also Count Dooku — a conflict of interest that a mercenary probably would be able to handle.

But wasn't Obi-Wan a bit suspicious at all that the entire conflict was staged? Is this addressed in the Clone Wars series? The Jedi seem to be perfectly happy fighting the real war without any suspicions that the war was a manufactured and orchestrated diversion.

Comment: Jango did not say "**Darth** Tyranus", he said only "Tyranus" ("I was recruited by a man called Tyranus"...), who at that point was not known to the Jedi yet.

Comment: Hmmmm a good point though. If you think about it. During the film they didn't know that it is DARTH tyranus BUT later on during the clone wars series I think they heard the name with darth by it a few times? Shouldn't have that made them wonder though? (got that thought when reading the question and the comment)

Comment: @RemyLebeau; in [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html) Jango does say **Darth** Tyranus, but I'm unsure if the script was actually followed

Comment: Dupe of [Why did the Jedi take the clone army without further thought?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91873/why-did-the-jedi-take-the-clone-army-without-further-thought)

Comment: Would anyone suspect an entire war to be a distraction?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Obi-Wan did not know who Tyranus was at that point and neither did the Jedi Order.
In [season 6, episode 10, of the Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_One), Obi-Wan finds out that Tyranus is Count Dooku.

He informs the Jedi Council of this and Yoda commands the council to keep this a secret. Yoda says that the Republic has no choice but to trust the Clones and that revealing this secret could create a huge public outcry against the war.

Below is a transcript of the relevant portions of the episode.

Kenobi finds out that Count Dooku is Darth Tyranus:

> **Minister Lom (to Count Dooku):** "You have no business left with the Pykes, Tyranus."
>   **Kenobi:** "Tyranus? You are the man called Tyranus?"
>   **Dooku:** "I told you everything you needed to know on Geonosis all those years ago, Kenobi."
>   ...

At the end of the episode, Yoda discusses this revelation with the Jedi Council:

> **Yoda:** "Know now we do, that guide the creation of the clones from the beginning, Dooku did."
>   **Mace Windu:** "Hmm, our enemy created an army for us."
>   **Ki Adi Mundi:** "If this was known, public confidence in the war effort, the Jedi, and the Republic would vanish. There would be mass chaos."
>   **Yoda:** "Cover up this discovery we must. No one, not even the Chancellor, may know. Valiant men the clones have proven to be. Saved my life, and yours they have many times. Believe in them, we must. Win this war swiftly we must, before our enemy's designs reach completion, whatever they may be."
>   **Mace Windu:** "Are you sure we are taking the right path?"
>   **Yoda:** "Hmm, the right path... no. The only path, yes. Designed by the Dark Lord of the Sith, this web is. For now, play his game, we must.*

Comment: ah perfect, this is exactly the conversation/information that I was looking for.  the show is aware of this apparent unease and addresses it.

Comment: That last line by Yoda should basically be be included in every answer to a question regarding the prequel movies.

Comment: @DangerZone, yes. The last line is what is pertinent. After the war has started, there only other possible option would be to find proof behind who was behind the war (which they did eventually) and try and use that proof to compel the other side that they should form a truce based on the farce. However, the goals of the separatists aren't even fully fleshed out, other than that they want to separate from the Republic. Would the fact that the clone army was set up by their own organizer cause them to change course? They still wanted to separate from the Republic. They'd just want Dooku's head.

Comment: Then why the Jedi didn't do anything about it if they knew that the Clone army was created by a Sith Lord?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar - That quoted exchange between Yoda, Mace Windu, and Ki Adi Mundi is your answer.